# RefineryCMS Image URL Incorrect

Tags: json, image, refinerycms, refinery

I'm writing an engine for RefineryCMS for a product photo gallery. I'm writing the gallery page using backbone and doing most of the rendering via frontend templates and javascript using backbone. So basically I am just sending my products to the client as JSON and the client builds the page.

Also the app is setup to save images to Amazon s3.

Now each product can have many Photos related to it. When I send these photos down as JSON I determine the url of the image which is stored as a Refinery::Image by calling

image.url()

and send the url to the client. Then in the client side code I use the url as the src attribute of an image tag.

However the url I send down does not exist on my server.

I'm not extremely familiar with image_fu and how it is goes about generating the server side images. If someone could help me figure out how to generate image urls that work that would be awesome.